# Vim NERDTree | Remap '<cr>' to 'go' | open file but remain in NerdTree window

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I'm trying to remap Nerdtree keys so that `<cr>` opens a file but the cursor stays in the nerdtree window. Nerdtree has this capability by default and can be triggered with the `g + o` key mapping. I want this mapping only when in Nerdtree.

From what I understand from the Nerdtree docs the functions this mapping calls is `NERDTree-go` which is shorthand for `'g' + NERDTreeMapActivateNode`

These are what I've tried in my vim rc from a combination of the NerdTree docs and from solutions posed for similar questions.

```
let NERDTree-go=<cr>

nnoremap <CR> :call nerdtree#ui_glue#invokeKeyMap("go")<CR>

nnoremap <CR> :call nerdtree#invokeKeyMap("go")

let g NERDTreeMapActivateNode = <cr>

let g NERDTree-go
```

There's also an api method which I think should work but a) it seems like it should be easy to do with a simple remap and b) I can't work out how to set it up. I got as far as getting it loaded but I just had the following in the vimscript file which caused an error:

```
NERDTreeAddKeyMap({
  'key': '<cr>',
  'callback': 'NERDTree-go',
  'scope': 'FileNode',
  'overide': '1'
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NERDTree normally is configured via `g:NERDTreeMap...` variables; unfortunately, there's no separate map option for `go`. From `:help NERDTree-go`:

> The key combo for this mapping is always "g" + NERDTreeMapActivateNode (see
>   NERDTree-o).

So, you have to do the remapping yourself. To apply this only to the NERDTree window, this needs to be a buffer-local mapping, triggered on opening of the NERDTree sidebar:

```
:autocmd FileType nerdtree nmap <buffer> <CR> go
```